# Cut your coat according to your cloth

Tags: expressions, proverbs

I have found two similar sayings in English which say: **undertake only what you have the money or ability to do and no more.** But apparantly they work only in British English, whilst I need something more epidemic and in common use in both Americans and Britons.

> - Cut your coat according to your cloth. (UK)
> - As long as your blanket you may stretch. (Perhaps a translation from another language)

What do the Americans say in the same sense?
What is the most common way yo say it in both AmE and BrE?

Comment: Never heard either saying, so both are probably obsolete.

Comment: "Cut your coat according to your cloth" is very common in the UK, and not at all obsolete.

Comment: I can't see why *undertake only what you have the money or ability to do and no more* would make any less sense in US English than in UK English. Why do you need to use something different than that?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest: "living within your means"

> live within (one's) means
>
> To go through each day, week, month, etc., without exceeding one's budget or without going into debt.

[TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/live+within+means)